# How does cron know what MTA to use?

Tags: cron, mail-transport-agent

How does cron know what MTA to use? Where is this info stored please? (Using Ubuntu KK.)

Edit: Here's the whole story: I enabled the MAILTO option in crontab, and scheduled some task. When the task got triggered, the system complained that there is no MTA installed, so I installed ssmtp. Interestingly, I never installed sendmail on my system, nor do I think it is installed by default. Hence all I have is ssmtp. Now, I need to make sure that whatever application does the emailing is bound to some specific NIC, hence it needs to be launched prefixed by firejail. The question is now, how do I know what email application is launched by cron, and how can I launch it with the firejail prefix.

Comment: maximum one MTA allowed on a system.

Comment: @gabor.zed: what if I install ssmtp and then tomorrow postfix without uninstalling ssmtp? Which one will be my MTA?

Comment: @gabor.zed there is no such restriction, although distros by convention, may enforce one.

Comment: @Aqualung the files installed by the `ssmtp` package on Ubuntu Kinetic can be found here:  https://packages.ubuntu.com/kinetic/amd64/ssmtp/filelist  . It includes a `/usr/bin/sendmail` for compatibility with OS utilities and scripts that assume the Sendmail MTA is present.  Are you sure cron complained and not the program/script you invoked in your cron job?

Answer (score 1):

If you read the man page, you will see there is a switch `-m` which states...

> This  option allows you to specify a shell command to use for sending
> Cron mail output instead of using sendmail(8) This command must accept
> a fully formatted mail message (with headers) on standard input and
> send it as a mail message to the recipients specified in the mail headers.  Specifying the string off (i.e., crond -m off) will disable the
> sending of mail.

In other words, it will call `sendmail` and the distro will likely ensure that a symlink has been set up to the already installed mta which should support it. If not, then the sending will fail.

Comment: Here's the whole story: I enabled the MAILTO option in crontab, and scheduled some task. When the task got triggered, the system complained that there is no MTA installed, so I installed ssmtp. Interestingly, I never installed sendmail on my system, nor do I think it is installed by default. Hence all I have is ssmtp. Now, I need to make sure that whatever application does the emailing is bound to some specific NIC, hence it needs to be launched prefixed by firejail. The question is now, how do I know what email application is launched by cron, and how can I launch it with the firejail prefix.

Comment: Run `which sendmail`. That will probably return `/usr/sbin/sendmail` which will be symlinked to your installed mta, If not, then do it manually. `cron` is only looking for the command `sendmail`, not the appication called `sendmail`.

Comment: Alright, many thanks for the replies! So cron is looking for the `sendmail` command. As far as I can tell, sendmail is a binary, so I am not very sure I can replace references to `ssmtp` with `firejail ssmtp` inside. Any ideas?

Comment: Like we have been saying, `sendmail` is symlinked to the correct binary, even `ssmtp` is able to run linked from `sendmail`. Look at the contents of the `ssmtp` package.